# Is this possible to send a java object to an obj-c, and obj-c to java via socket?

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets

Ok, just a simple question, I would like to send a object via java and obj-c. Is this possible to do so? Or I need to change the `object` to `string` or something first, and convert it back in to the receive side? Thanks.

Comment: Obviously you cannot sent the `Object` via a socket as the `Object` is a data representation in memory and this is language specific. You need to serialize the data somehow, not necessarily to a `String`. Google's [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) provide a cross platform was to serialize `Object`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to send a serialised Java object to objective C over a socket, but recovering it is difficult since you'd need to write a library to parse the binary data stream. It's possible someone has already written such a library.

It's easier to send objects encoded in JSON or XML, or with Google protocol buffers.

Comment: There'a also Apache Thrift which will do this (it bundles the RPC layer as well)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to send a object via java and obj-c

This is the classic problem of communication between different systems/languages.
The solution has always been `XML` (usually `SOAP` which is not my taste) and nowadays the options @Joni mentions in his answer